# How to implement UIPageViewController with a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I took the [Photo Scroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) example from Apple's website and tried to implement my own Album by copying the code. Now, the `UIScrollView` is not visible. How do I make it appear?

The only code change that I made was in creating the `UIPageViewController`. In my case, it's a `UIViewController` that is opening it and not the `AppDelegate`.

```
@implementation BasePhotoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // kick things off by making the first page

        PhotoViewController *pageZero = [PhotoViewController photoViewControllerForPageIndex:0];
        if (pageZero != nil)
        {
            // assign the first page to the pageViewController (our rootViewController)
            //UIPageViewController *pageViewController = (UIPageViewController *)    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
            UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:0 navigationOrientation:0 options:nil];
            //UIPageViewController *pageViewController = (UIPageViewController *)self.parentViewController;
            pageViewController.dataSource = self;

            [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[pageZero]
                                     direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                      animated:NO
                                    completion:NULL];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding the `pageViewController`'s view as a subview of `BasePhotoViewController`'s view. Your `BasePhotoViewController` class should look something like this. Note the code in `viewDidLoad`.

**BasePhotoViewController.h:**

```
@interface BasePhotoViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageViewController * pageViewController;
@end
```

**BasePhotoViewController.m:**

```
#import "BasePhotoViewController.h"
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@implementation BasePhotoViewController

@synthesize pageViewController;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        PhotoViewController *pageZero = [PhotoViewController photoViewControllerForPageIndex:0];
        if (pageZero != nil)
        {
            self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:0
                                                                      navigationOrientation:0
                                                                                    options:nil];
            self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

            [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[pageZero]
                                              direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                               animated:NO
                                             completion:NULL];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

# pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc viewControllerBeforeViewController:(PhotoViewController *)vc
{
    NSUInteger index = vc.pageIndex;
    return [PhotoViewController photoViewControllerForPageIndex:(index - 1)];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc viewControllerAfterViewController:(PhotoViewController *)vc
{
    NSUInteger index = vc.pageIndex;
    return [PhotoViewController photoViewControllerForPageIndex:(index + 1)];
}

@end
```

**Note:** I've initialised the `UIPageViewController` in `initWithCoder:` because Apple's [Photo Scroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) code uses a storyboard. I removed the `UIPageViewController` from the storyboard and created a `BasePhotoViewController` in its place. If you are not loading `BasePhotoViewController` from a storyboard, you should move the code in `initWithCoder:` to the appropriate initialiser.

**EDIT:** See this [sample project](https://github.com/stephsharp/PhotoScroller) on github.