# Sample code for ios6 based scrollview with pagination and zooming features for an array of images

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

Can anybody help me with the sample code for embedding a zoomable scroll view within a paging scroll view so that each page can be zoomed and panned individually?

Also the navigation structure is like tab bar controller --> navigation controller with buttons (on push of the buttons) --> view controller where in the horizontal scrollview of images has to be implemented with pagination and zooming.

Here is the link to the tutorial that I followed: [How To Use UIScrollView to Scroll and Zoom Content](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)

The code I've implemented is following:

```
#import "ViewCorpBrochureController.h"

@interface ViewCorpBrochureController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pageImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pageViews;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

- (void)loadVisiblePages;
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page;
- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page;


- (void)centerScrollViewContents;
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;



@end

@implementation ViewCorpBrochureController

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl = _pageControl;

@synthesize pageImages = _pageImages;
@synthesize pageViews = _pageViews;


@synthesize imageView = _imageview;



- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // Get the location within the image view where we tapped
    CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

// Get a zoom scale that's zoomed in slightly, capped at the maximum zoom scale specified       by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale * 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale);

    // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
    CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // Zoom out slightly, capping at the minimum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale / 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MAX(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale);
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:newZoomScale animated:YES];
}


#pragma mark -

- (void)loadVisiblePages {
    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

    // Update the page control
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

    // Work out which pages we want to load
    NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
    NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;

    // Purge anything before the first page
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
        [self purgePage:i];
    }
    for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
        [self loadPage:i];
    }
    for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
        [self purgePage:i];
    }
}

- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
        // If it's outside the range of what we have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }

    // Load an individual page, first seeing if we've already loaded it
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

        UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]];
        newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        newPageView.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
    }
}

- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page {
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
        // If it's outside the range of what we have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }

    // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView != [NSNull null]) {
        [pageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}


#pragma mark -



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




   self.title = @"CorporateBrochure";


    self.pageImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB2.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB3.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB4.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB5.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB6.jpg"],
                       nil];

    NSInteger pageCount = self.pageImages.count;

    // Set up the page control
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;

    // Set up the array to hold the views for each page
    self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
        [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }


    /* If I use this the subview appears below the image
     UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB2.jpg"];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
    */



    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:)];
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];


     }


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.pageImages.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);

    [self loadVisiblePages];

}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.scrollView = nil;
    self.pageControl = nil;
    self.pageImages = nil;
    self.pageViews = nil;
}



- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    // Return the view that we want to zoom
    return self.imageView;
}




- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}



#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Load the pages which are now on screen
    [self loadVisiblePages];
}



- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // The scroll view has zoomed, so you need to re-center the contents
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

@end
```

Comment: Try explaining the problem you're having, not just asking for a solution 'asap'

Comment: Hi damienc actually i was trying to implement the scroll, pan & zoom scrollview example of ray wenderlich tutorial and got struck when applying it for an array of images. Could you please help me out.

Comment: With all regards to TBlue I've tried hard to implement a zoomable scrollview with pagination but yep I've just joined stackoverflow so couldn't post my code properly would surely post the code if you need me to.

Comment: Please do post it, and explain the problem you're having.  Please do this as an edit to your question. Perhaps a link to the tutorial, as well.

Comment: Thank you very much sir :) I am going to paste the link & the code as well as per your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific issue you are having with Ray Wenderlich's tutorial?

Apple's documentation has a very good example of how to implement a paging scroll view, see the [Photo Scroller sample code here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html). I would suggest starting there.

From the above link:

> "PhotoScroller" demonstrates the use of embedded UIScrollViews and
>   CATiledLayer to create a rich user experience for displaying and
>   paginating photos that can be individually panned and zoomed.

Note: If your images are not overly large, you can get away with not using `CATiledLayer`.

**EDIT 1:** See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17207056/1367622) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171777/how-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-with-a-uiscrollview/) about how to modify Apple's Photo Scroller code to make the `UIPageViewController` a subview of your own view controller (and not the `rootViewController`).

**EDIT 2:** See this [sample project](https://github.com/stephsharp/PhotoScroller) on github.

Comment: Could you please see the code again there after the code snippet for page views what iam trying to do is the addition of subview to the existing page view but the thing is Iam unable to load the image fullscreen as of now the view is appearing below the first image itself.

Comment: I tried to implement apple photo scroller example also but because of the complex navigational architecture we are having in our project we are getting the root view controller error. I hope am able to clearly present my problem.

Comment: @AlamHammad See my edit, hopefully that might help you get past the root view controller error.

Comment: What should i do for the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate.m?

Comment: I have implemented whatever you suggested in your response but my views are appearing blank(black) :(.

If possible could you share with me any working example of the same.

Comment: @AlamHammad I uploaded my sample code to github. See my edit above for the link.

Comment: It is really appreciating that there are great good people like you who help others and I should say 'THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!' for your help. 
Just want to know how can I make it go full screen for my images for iPad right now they are coming at the bottom?

Comment: No problems, happy to help :) I'm not too sure about the issue with your images on the iPad though. I just tested my sample code, and it appears to be working fine. You might need to post a screenshot and some of your code.

Comment: In my project the image size is 1536*2048, and they are appearing attached at the bottom in a frame size of say 320*640 px

Comment: Is it only an issue on the iPad (and working fine on iPhone)? It's really hard to say what could be causing this without some code to look at. I would suggest this is something you could ask as a new question.